# Specific web pages that should be light are a burden on the processors

Tags: arch-linux, chrome

I've been realizing for quite some time that some specific pages are a real burden for my browser to open. I hear the fans at full on speed and the processors seem to have a unusually high load when checking `htop`.

I'm not very familiar with web programming, but it seems to be something related to Javascript. It appears to happen independently of browser (I've tried Chromium, Chrome and Firefox) and it's always the same pages. That happens even when I'm not doing anything else with my OS except viewing those pages.

Some examples of pages that spur that behavior are [this page](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/best-rolling-release-linux-distributions/) and [Thesaurus](https://www.thesaurus.com/).

*Some relevant info:*

I'm using an up-to-date Arch Linux with cinnamon.

Here's a screeshot of `htop` as the issue was happening (at the time of the screenshot, browsing the internet was the only thing I was doing):

[image]

Comment: I want to say something about the state of the modern web, but this isn't the place for ranting. If you visit a lot of the same sites, and you're technically minded,  there's a browser extension called 'uMatrix', from the same guy that does uBlock Origin. It's basically an old-school firewall but *only* for your browser. With it, you can block most anything and only allow the bare minimum web content to run. There is a learning curve and time investment. Fortunately, you only need to invest the time once per site - but the web will be much lighter and easier on your CPU.

Comment: @KGIII thanks for the suggestion (and I'm actually curious to hear your rant about modern web). I'll look into that, although I'd like a higher level solution since most of my web browsing is done via incognito windows. I'm guessing such a firewall would only be active in regular non-incognito browsing.

Comment: Nah, it works in incognito mode and I don't think there's a higher level solution. If I go to those sites and let them load, they'll chew at my CPU resources as well. As you noted, it's browser independent and browsers decide/control all that which means there's no real higher level solution - as far as I know. Your only realistic option is, again as far as I know, to block the stuff from loading at the browser level. You can buy a faster CPU, but they'll just find new ways to use it to load stuff that can be displayed just fine without any scripting at all.

Comment: @KGIII well, that sucks. Atl least it seems like I'm not alone in this. But thanks for the suggestion, uMatrix looks pretty good!

Comment: It has a learning curve but it's not that hard. You can also backup your settings and export your settings to use on other devices. Sadly, everyone's needs are unique - so there isn't some sort of previously configured uMatrix settings you can import. It's a bit like NoScript - but with a lot more refinement and a smaller footprint. Good luck and, trust me, you don't want me to start ranting! By the way, once you have uMatrix installed and start looking at things, you'll be amazed at how much scripting is needlessly loaded at sites that don't need it or even benefit from it.